# numerical simulation of 4 coupled nonlinear PDEs

Tags: partial-differential-equations

i have 4 nonlinear coupled PDEs with 8 BC eqs and i'm looking for a numerical method to simulate those in matlab.
i can solve any ODE in M file by discretizing equations by writing the basic definitions of integral and differential and put my equations in a loop.
 i'd like to know if there is a similar method to do that?

these are my equations[image: 4 coupled nonlinear pdes]

Comment: In Matlab: [The Partial Differential Equation toolbox](http://www.mathworks.com/products/pde/). [Start here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/pde/getting-started-with-partial-differential-equation-toolbox.html).

Comment: my equations are nonlinear and coupled and they consist of integrals that i cannot write them in the standard forms